# scope.f1 undefined error while uploading a file

Tags: c#, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm new about coding AngularJS. I have applied the AngularJS upload file tutorial which i found via internet. When i tried to upload file i am getting an error `$scope.f1` undefined error. [scopeerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyOQl.jpg) I tried everything but unfortunately i couldn't fix the error.

Can you help me about the issue?

Controller.js

```js
Controller.js

angular.module("ciciannemApp.controllers",[]).
controller("MainController", function ($scope, ProductService) {
    $scope.message = "Main Controller";

    ProductService.GetProductsFromDb().then(function (d) {
        $scope.listProducts = d.data.list;
    })

    $scope.DeleteProduct = function (id, index) {
        $scope.listProducts.splice(index, 1);
        ProductService.DeleteProduct(id);
    }
}).
controller("AddProductController", function ($scope, ProductService) {
        $scope.message = "Add Product Details";
        $scope.AddProduct = function ()
        {
            ProductService.AddProduct($scope.product);
        }
}).
controller("EditProductController", function ($scope, ProductService, $routeParams) {
        $scope.message = "Edit Product Details";

        var id = $routeParams.id;
        ProductService.GetProductById(id).then(function (d) {
            $scope.product = d.data.product;
        })

        $scope.UpdateProduct = function () {
            ProductService.UpdateProduct($scope.product);
        }
    }).
controller("AddImageController", ["$scope", "$q", "ProductService", function ($scope, $q,  ProductService) {
       
    //Variables
    $scope.Message = "";
    $scope.FileInvalidMessage;
    $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = null;
    $scope.Description = "";
    $scope.IsFormSubmitted = false;
    $scope.IsFileValid = false;
    $scope.IsFormValid = false;
    var SelectFileForUpload = null;

    //Form Validation
    $scope.$watch("f1.$valid", function (isValid) {
        $scope.IsFormValid = isValid;
    });
    //File Validation
    $scope.ChechFileValid = function (file) {
        var isValid = false;
        if ($scope.SelectedFileForUpload != null) {
            if ((file.type == 'image/png' || file.type == 'image/jpeg' || file.type == 'image/gif') && file.size <= 512 * 1024) {
                $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "";
                isValid = true;
            }
            else {
                $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "Selected file is Invalid.(only file type png, jpeg and gif and 512 kb size allowed )";
            }
        }
        else {
            $scope.FileInvalidMessage = "Image Required!";
        }
        if (isValid) {
            $scope.IsFileValid = true;
            $scope.IsFormValid = true;
        }
    };
    //File Select 
    $scope.selectFileforUpload = function (file) {
        $scope.SelectedFileForUpload = file[0];
    }
    //Save File
    $scope.AddImage = function () {
        $scope.IsFormSubmitted = true;
        $scope.Message = "";
        $scope.ChechFileValid($scope.SelectedFileForUpload);
        if ($scope.IsFormValid && $scope.IsFileValid) {
            ProductService.AddImage($scope.SelectedFileForUpload, $scope.Description).then(function (d) {
                alert(d.Message);
                ClearForm();
            }, function (e) {
                alert(e);
      
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.Message = "All Fields are required";
        }
    };
    //Clear Form
    function ClearForm() {
        $scope.Description = "";
        alert($scope.Description);
        angular.forEach(angular.element("input[type='file']"), function (inputElem) {
            angular.element(inputElem).val(null);
        });
        $scope.f1.$setPristine();
        $scope.IsFormSubmitted = false;
    }
}]).
factory("ProductService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetProductsFromDb = function ()
    {
        return $http.get("/Product/GetProducts");
    }
    fac.GetProductById = function (id)
    {
        return $http.get("/Product/GetProductById", { params: { id: id } });
    }
    fac.AddProduct = function (product)
    {
        $http.post("/Product/AddProduct", product).then(function (response) {
            var response = "Ürün Eklendi"; alert(response);
        }, function (response) {
            var response = "Hata Oluştu"; alert(response);
        });
    }
    fac.UpdateProduct = function (product) {
        $http.post("/Product/UpdateProduct", product).then(function (response) {
            var response = "Ürün Güncellendi"; alert(response);
        }, function (response) {
            var response = "Hata Oluştu"; alert(response);
        })
    }
    fac.DeleteProduct = function (id) {
        $http.post("/Product/DeleteProduct", { id: id }).then(function (response) {
            var response = "Ürün Silindi"; alert(response);
        }, function (response) {
            var response = "Hata Oluştu"; alert(response);
        })
    }
    fac.AddImage = function (file, description) {
        
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        formData.append('description', description);
        
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.post("/Product/AddImage", formData, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        })
                        .then(function (d) {
                            defer.resolve(d);
        }, function () {
            defer.reject("File Upload Failed!");
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }
    return fac;
}])

App.js

var app = angular.module("ciciannemApp", ["ciciannemApp.controllers", "ngRoute"]);

app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when("/", { templateUrl: "/Partials/ProductList.html", controller: "MainController" }).
    when("/AddProduct", { templateUrl: "/Partials/AddProduct.html", controller: "AddProductController" }).
    when("/EditProduct/:id", { templateUrl: "/Partials/EditProduct.html", controller: "EditProductController" }).
    when("/AddImage/", { templateUrl: "/Partials/AddImage.html", controller: "AddImageController" }).
    otherwise({redirectTo: "/"})

}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Main Controller </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="ciciannemApp">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

emphasized text
Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: post your controller's code and template, noone can guess what your code looks like. For now I can only tell you that a variable is undefined.

Comment: i have uploaded to GIT to be seen easily

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that, but no-one can get access to your git repo if you don't provide a link, plus you should avoid posting link to external resources for element that are essential to the question. What would happen if you delete the repo and someone is asking the same thing, he won't get any code, and might not be able to relate to his problem.

Comment: Ok.Thanks. I've added code